# What is the principal of Inductive Conductivity sensor?

Tags: sensor, transformer, measurement, conductivity

What is the principal of Inductive Conductivity sensor which uses two coupled coils to estimate conductivity?

[image]
[Image Source](http://www.emerson.com/documents/automation/application-data-theory-application-of-conductivity-en-68442.pdf)

I understand that the eddy current losses changes with the conductivity, and eddy current loops may increase total mutual coupling, however, I am not very sure how conductivity is measured in these sensors. Is it by estimating the resistance of the loop, or just fitting the measured voltage to pre-calibrated data?

<s>For example, [this paper says](http://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/15/9/20990/pdf) (**Edit: Not the same as above - this uses two coupled coils**)</s>

> we can conclude that the emf2  is related with the medium through the variable /mu which is related with the amount of salts dissolved in the water.

(emf2 is induced voltage in secondary coil) however, to my understanding, permeability is independent of the conductivity, instead, imaginary part of the permittivity is determined by the conductivity

Comment: The two devices are different beasts operating on similar but different principles. Nowhere in the 2nd document could I find a quote that used the word "secondary".

Comment: The are not coils per-se. They are iron/ferrite cored toroids.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So two things to understand.

1) Toroids have a tight magnetic field, and so the two toroids don't couple to each other in air. (or if you put magnetic rod through the holes)

2) If you put a loop of wire through the hole of a toroid, it forms a 1 turn winding on that toroid, and it will try and force a current through it.

So the conductive fluid (in blue) forms a rather resistive loop of wire through both toroids, i.e it forms two secondaries tied together.

(R1+R2) * N^2 = V/A

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSUHDv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is an alternative to using a single toroid, where the fluid forms a shorted turn secondary. In the two toroid case there is no current out the second toroid when there is no conductivity.

In the single toroid case there is always magnetising current through the toroid, and you need to cancel out the magnetising current, usually done by having a synchronous detector that only detects the in-phase (resistive) component. Then you still have residual core loss. So the two toroid version probably has simpler circuitry, and works better for weaker conductivity.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftvehO.png)</sup>

Wish someone told me that before I developed the single toroid type.

Comment: Got it! So the conductivity is estimated by measured resistance and the geometry of current path of the sensor?

Comment: There is certainly someone here who knows a lot more about them than I do : You just introduced me to the two toroid type, never saw it before. Obvious with hindsight. GRRR! –

Comment: Good explanation +1

Answer (score 1):

Conducting materials exhibit a phenomenon called paramagnetism.  In space, a magnetic field has to fend for itself; in a conductive medium, that field will set up eddy currents that reinforce it, and the conductive medium acts like a magnetic core--not directing the field so much, but just reinforcing it.  It exhibits apparent permeability due to the sympathetic currents.  Thus, the coupling between the coils will change depending on the conductivity of the medium.

Comment: They are iron core toroids not solenoid coils. If you put an iron rod through the two cores, they still aren't coupled.

Comment: Aside from that, do you have any idea if two solenoids wound around a plastic pipe can measure conductivity by magnetic coupling through ionic fluid?

Comment: I think my second [link in the question](http://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/15/9/20990/pdf) uses something similar - using two coupled coils