# Electrical conductivity circuit help, with two solenoids

Tags: circuit-analysis, electromagnetism, inductance, conductivity, mutual-inductance

I have a project im working on but cant seem to figure out the basic of the circuit.

The principal of the circuit is two solenoids wrapped around a chemistry glass making a magnetic field. The purpose is to measure salinty of the water in the cup. Plan is to amplify the signal enough to see a clear difference in salinty levels, which shall become proportinal with a 4-20mA signal.

[image: Picture of the model] The two solenoids around the glass.

[image: Two solenoids] Picture is from an pdf.

My question is, what components is needed in the circuit and why? How much Vpeak-peak and hertz would you recommend? Im using an signal generator and  a osciloscope to measure.

Comment: Usually for measuring salt concentration used some electrodes, immersed. Conductivity measuring. Where did you get that idea from?

Comment: Using electrodeless sensors are very common. Inductive method gives a more robust sensor and mid range measurment. To give u a better referance i can send a link to a similar question on this site: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/388984/what-is-the-principal-of-inductive-conductivity-sensor 
This is same principal, im just using two solenoids.

Comment: Have you actually modeled the fields and currents for this? It is very different from two [fully submerged toroidal coils](https://bit.ly/3udX1HE).

Comment: I have no models thus far no. Im just concerned about the basics, by that i mean the fundemental to amplify a signal based on mutual conductance. What components i need. Thanks for answering by the way. Your link doesnt work unfortunaly, but how is so different?

Comment: @Benjamin, your system is not the same as the question you linked to. The linked question uses **coils wound on torroidal cores** and relies on current flow through the cores of the toroids and looping back around the outside. They are like current transformers. Your system doesn't have the current transformer action and doesn't have a fluid current path.

Comment: Very true mate, but the fundemental is the same though, is it not? 

Two coils, 1 reciever and 1 driver, whereas the driver will make a magnetic field with AC signal and the reciever will have different output signal based on the salinty in the water in the cup?

Ive tried some and i get a little spike in voltage by putting water inside.

Comment: No, you are making a poor air / water-cored transformer coupled magnetically. The other is making two transformers coupled electrically (by common current circuit via the fluid). See [Henry Crun](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/388991/73158)'s answer to your linked question. He explains that there is **no** magnetic coupling between the two coils. Yours is **all** magnetic coupling so they're fundamentally differnt.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. If i where to make two toroids, wound them myself, what type of wire would be recommended? Will a not insulated copper alloyed wire do the job? And is there some prefered diameter (outer circle diameter and inner circle diameter)?